# Получение информации из файла Json

Tags: python, json

я хотел бы из файла json такого вида:

```
{

"items": [
    {
        "id": 81918430,
        "scrambledId": "81918430.4a552a",
        "company": {
            "name": "Goldbeck GmbH",
            "link": "https://www.xing.com/pages/goldbeckgmbh",
            "kununuData": {
                "companyProfileUrl": "https://www.kununu.com/de/goldbeck",
                "ratingAverage": 4.0,
                "ratingCount": 1625
            }
        },
        "favoritePosting": null,
        "highlight": null,
        "isBookmarked": false,
        "isProjob": false,
        "link": "https://www.xing.com/jobs/bielefeld-trainees-controlling-finance-81918430?paging_context=search&search_query%5Blimit%5D=20&search_query%5Boffset%5D=0",
        "location": "Bielefeld",
        "position": 0,
        "thumbnail": "https://www.xing.com/imagecache/public/scaled_original_image/eyJ1dWlkIjoiYjMyZjI1ZTUtNmM2NS00YzcwLWE5ZDUtZmUxNGVhNjNlMjA1IiwiYXBwX2NvbnRleHQiOiJlbnRpdHktcGFnZXMiLCJtYXhfd2lkdGgiOjE5MiwibWF4X2hlaWdodCI6MTkyfQ?signature=6f7cb2e605623a476c5644e704ddbaa56ca4edcb0cab834bb0487e52e112453b",
        "activatedAt": "2022-02-23T10:49:15Z",
        "path": "/jobs/bielefeld-trainees-controlling-finance-81918430?paging_context=search&search_query%5Blimit%5D=20&search_query%5Boffset%5D=0",
        "slug": "bielefeld-trainees-controlling-finance-81918430",
        "title": "Trainees (m/w/d) Controlling & Finance",
        "trackingToken": "69e0f737bc2711ecbee8126facd3d9c1.0.81918430"
    },
```

Получить первый и второй "link". Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/json

Answer (score 0):

А в чём сложность? `items` - это список, по нему нужно итерироваться:

```py
import json

s = """
{

"items": [
    {
        "id": 81918430,
        "scrambledId": "81918430.4a552a",
        "company": {
            "name": "Goldbeck GmbH",
            "link": "https://www.xing.com/pages/goldbeckgmbh",
            "kununuData": {
                "companyProfileUrl": "https://www.kununu.com/de/goldbeck",
                "ratingAverage": 4.0,
                "ratingCount": 1625
            }
        },
        "favoritePosting": null,
        "highlight": null,
        "isBookmarked": false,
        "isProjob": false,
        "link": "https://www.xing.com/jobs/bielefeld-trainees-controlling-finance-81918430?paging_context=search&search_query%5Blimit%5D=20&search_query%5Boffset%5D=0",
        "location": "Bielefeld",
        "position": 0,
        "thumbnail": "https://www.xing.com/imagecache/public/scaled_original_image/eyJ1dWlkIjoiYjMyZjI1ZTUtNmM2NS00YzcwLWE5ZDUtZmUxNGVhNjNlMjA1IiwiYXBwX2NvbnRleHQiOiJlbnRpdHktcGFnZXMiLCJtYXhfd2lkdGgiOjE5MiwibWF4X2hlaWdodCI6MTkyfQ?signature=6f7cb2e605623a476c5644e704ddbaa56ca4edcb0cab834bb0487e52e112453b",
        "activatedAt": "2022-02-23T10:49:15Z",
        "path": "/jobs/bielefeld-trainees-controlling-finance-81918430?paging_context=search&search_query%5Blimit%5D=20&search_query%5Boffset%5D=0",
        "slug": "bielefeld-trainees-controlling-finance-81918430",
        "title": "Trainees (m/w/d) Controlling & Finance",
        "trackingToken": "69e0f737bc2711ecbee8126facd3d9c1.0.81918430"
    }
]
}
"""

jsn = json.loads(s)

for item in jsn['items']:
    print(item['company']['link'])
    print(item['link'])
```

Вывод:

```
https://www.xing.com/pages/goldbeckgmbh
https://www.xing.com/jobs/bielefeld-trainees-controlling-finance-81918430?paging_context=search&search_query%5Blimit%5D=20&search_query%5Boffset%5D=0
```